Creating Repeating text box and after pressing submit, the box generates a Nintex form - i am a beginner in power apps
I want to have one repeating text box, and whenever this text box is filled and submitted, each text box generates its own Nintex form (Nintex form I already have created). So if I have a total of 3 boxes after using the repeating function, in the end, after pressing the submit button, I would have 3 Nintex forms.
How can I achieve this in PowerApps?
I have no idea how I can achieve this connection of a box generating a Nintex form which I already have created. I have seen a few YouTube videos on repeating boxes, and I honestly don't know if it will work or not.

You can use collection to store to store your data. And after submitting a box use DateTime Stamp as ID for the form and the submitted text.
